# How to deploy GWT on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt, war

I'm trying to figure out why when I create a WAR for my GWT project, I'm unable to get the webapp up and running like in my development mode.

In my development mode, I'm using googles plugin:

```
Run As --> Web Application
```

and I get the `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Bspdir.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`

**works great!**

note that I'm not using GAE, I unchecked the Use GoogleApp Engine, and in my project properties facet I added the Dynamic Web Module.

So now, I wish to go to production and I'm 'WARing' the project by right clicking on the **project name**`-->export-->Web-->War-->`

```
Web project: bspdir
```

[see screenshot below] I upload the WAR file to my `/usr/local/tomcat6/webapps` and type the following in the URL:

http://MY_SERVER.com:8080/bspdir/

http://MY_SERVER.com:8080/Bspdir/

http://MY_SERVER.com:8080/bspdir/Bspdir.html

and always get the same error message: **HTTP Status 404 - /bspdir/**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it work when you make and copy the war file manually?

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'make and copy manually'? I'm doing this manually for production. Thanks

Comment: I mean making a war archive from the relevant files and directories and copying them manually to the appropriate Tomcat directory (without an IDE wizard).

Comment: Yes, I tried that with jar -cvf command but it didn't work either (it created the war but when I placed it under the webapps  - nothing). I'm not sure even what is the URL I should point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after numerous attempts I got it right. Go to the WAR folder of your app (command line) and create it manually with:

`jar cvf PROJECT_NAME.war *`

I uploaded this war file to my tomcat production webapps and it works.

When I tried to create a war file with eclipse it didn't create a complete file (not sure why), thus the 404 error.

Comment: Those are exactly the instructions I gave you - except that you build the `.war` file on the command line (which is optional). That much for "not sure why"...

Comment: you may need to set the path for jar....
otherwise....'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 2):

The "Export WAR file" action is the wrong approach as it won't include the GWT specific settings and artifacts.

1. Right-click the web project: Google -> GWT Compile, this should give you a `/<your-web-project>/war` folder or similar
   (specified in projects settings -> Google -> Web Application)
2. Expand the web project in the project explorer or navigator
3. Right-click the `war` folder: Export -> General -> Archive File
4. Rename the exported ZIP file from `*.zip` to `*.war`

Answer (score 0):

Tried to compile your application first (Google -> GWT Compile)? When it compiled, try to deploy it once again. If it still does not work you should check your web.xml, see e. g. [Deploy GWT .war with Servlet in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460936/deploy-gwt-war-with-servlet-in-tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @Marcel Stör and @adhg is right way, if you are not as stupid as me and didn't convert your Eclipse GWT project into Maven project and thus completely destroy any automation.

So, if you have project, that working fine in dev mode, running from Eclipse, but your `war` directory is empty, the following is for you: it's pretty simple to make WAR manually.

I assume, that your project is calling "MyProj"

1. Right mouse click on your project in Package Explorer and choose GWT -> Compile.
2. Start you favorite file manager and create some temp directory (anywhere on your drive) to store your deployment files, for ex, `myproj_deploy`.
3. Go to `MyProj/target`. You'll find directory, called something like `MyProj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. Copy it content into `myproj_deploy` dir.
4. Under `MyProj/target` there is `classes` directory. Go inside and you'll find folder, called "main" and root of your `WEB-INF/classes` dir, so create `myproj_deploy/WEB-INF/classes` directory and copy content of `MyProj/target/classes` into it, except "main" direcrory.
5. Now, go to `MyProj/target/main/webapp`. Of course, you can recognize these files. Here is your `WEB-INF/web.xml`, your host HTML, your css's, etc. Copy all into root of `myproj_deploy`.
   You are almost ready.
6. Go to `$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmpN/wtpwebapps/MyProj/WEB-INF/` and copy `lib` directory into `myproj_deploy/WEB-INF/`. That is your project library dependencies, and it's easiest way to don't forget to include some library into WAR.
7. Pack content of `myproj_deploy` into WAR as shown in @adhg answer and copy this WAR onto your Tomcat webapps dir.
8. Enjoy.

I had spent a few hours to find this solution, may be this post will help someone to save some time.

EDIT:

1. I don't know, why, but before processing p.1, clear 'target' directory of your project.
2. At p.6 copy with replacement 'classes' directory too.